# Force run a recipe (--assume-old=target)

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to force a recipe for "output.file", even though it is up-to-date.

- I have already tried `make --assume-old=output.file output.file`, but it does not run the recipe again.
- In case you are curious: use case:

  - I want to use this together with `--dry-run` to find out the command that produce a target.
- I ended up hiding the file to run `make --dry-run output.file`, but I was hoping for something more elegant + FMI: for future debugging makefile.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misunderstanding what that option does: it does *exactly the opposite* of what you hoped; from the man page:

```
   -o file, --old-file=file, --assume-old=file
        Do not remake the file file even if it is older than its dependen‐
        cies, and do not remake anything on account of  changes  in  file.
        Essentially  the  file  is  treated  as very old and its rules are
        ignored.
```

You *want* `output.file` to be remade, so using `-o` is clearly not what you want.

There is no option in GNU make to say "always rebuild this target".  What you can do is tell make to pretend that *some prerequisite* of the target you want to be rebuilt has been updated.  See this option:

```
   -W file, --what-if=file, --new-file=file, --assume-new=file
        Pretend  that  the  target file has just been modified.  When used
        with the -n flag, this shows you what would happen if you were  to
        modify  that file.  Without -n, it is almost the same as running a
        touch command on the given file before running make,  except  that
        the modification time is changed only in the imagination of make.
```

Say for example your `output.file` had a prerequisite `input.file`.  Then if you run:

```
make -W input.file
```

it will show you what rules it would run, which would include rebuilding `output.file`.